# url decode - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, urlencode, bookmarklet, urldecode

why does the following decoded script not work? The original code seems to run just fine.

```
javascript:(function(s){try{s=document.selection.createRange().text}catch(_)  {s=document.getSelection()}prompt('State the question and answer below.','Q.' s '')})
```

original code:

```
javascript:%28function%28s%29%7Btry%7Bs=document.selection.createRange%28%29.text%7Dcatch%28_%29%7Bs=document.getSelection%28%29%7Dprompt%28%27State the question and answer below.%27,%27Q.%27+s+%27%27%29%7D%29%28%29
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It decoded the `+` sign to a space, try this:

```
javascript:(function(s){try{s=document.selection.createRange().text}catch(_)  {s=document.getSelection()}prompt('State the question and answer below.','Q.'+s+'')})
```

The difference: change `' s '` to this `'+s+'`

Answer (score 0):

don't unescape the + sign and add () to the end:

```
javascript:(function(s){try{s=document.selection.createRange().text}catch(_)  {s=document.getSelection()}prompt('State the question and answer below.','Q.' s '')})
should be
javascript:(function(s){try{s=document.selection.createRange().text}catch(_){s=document.getSelection()}prompt('State the question and answer below.','Q.'+s+'')})()
```